# How to run current RSpec test in VIM + Rails.vim + Ubuntu?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, vim, rspec, rails.vim

It says everywhere:

- Interface to rake.  Use :Rake to run the current test, spec, or feature.  Use :.Rake to do a focused run of just the method, example, or scenario on the current line.  :Rake can also run arbitrary migrations, load individual fixtures, and more.  :help rails-rake

But when I'm at my _spec.rb file, and type `:Rake` - it just closes VIM, does nothing and outputs `Please hit Enter to continue`. It's not running current test.

Anyone knows?

Answer (score 1):

Try `:.Rake` or `:%Rake` to run current file / current test.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to give [vim-test](https://github.com/janko/vim-test) a try?

It's a vim wrapper for running tests on different granularities.

To run the nearest spec for example, run `:TestNearest` and enter.

The readme lists the following mappings for quicker test running:

```
nmap <silent> t<C-n> :TestNearest<CR>
nmap <silent> t<C-f> :TestFile<CR>
nmap <silent> t<C-s> :TestSuite<CR>
nmap <silent> t<C-l> :TestLast<CR>
nmap <silent> t<C-g> :TestVisit<CR>
```

NB: Vim-test supports major languages so running your tests in different languages won't change.